# R loop with different values

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

Is there a way to create loop indices different from each other, without going through the combinations like I did here with the if statement?

```
for (i in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
for (j in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
 for (z in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
   for (t in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
     for (k in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
       for (m in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
         for (l in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
           for (r in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
             for (s in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
               for (d in names(Category[,-c(1:2, 13:63)])){
               if (z!=j & j!=i & z!=i & t!=z & t!=j & t!=i & k!=t & k!=z & k!=j & k!=i& m!=i & m!=z & m!=j & m!=t & m!=k & l!=i & l!=z & l!=j & l!=t & l!=k & l!=m & r!=i & r!=z & r!=j & r!=t & r!=k & r!=m & r!=l & s!=i & s!=z & s!=j & s!=t & s!=k & s!=m & s!=l & s!=r & d!=i & d!=z & d!=j & d!=t & d!=k & d!=m & d!=l & d!=r & d!=s ){
                 n<-n+1
                 assign(paste0("model_",n),lmer(
                   as.formula(
                     paste(
                       names(Category)[2], "~" ,paste(i, "+", j ,"+",z, "+",t,  "+",k,  "+",m, "+",l, "+",r, "+",s, "+",d), 
                       '+ (1|', names(Category)[1], ')' 
                     )
                     
                   ),
                   data=Category))      }}}}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to generate a bunch of formulae by taking all possible combinations of variables. Take a look at `expand.grid` and `apply`. Here is a small example:

```
df <- data.frame("a"=letters[6:10],
                 "b"=letters[1:5],
                 "c"=letters[11:15])

df <- expand.grid(df)

apply(df[1:10,], MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) paste("y ~",paste0(x,collapse = "+")))
```

**Output**

```
1           2           3           4           5           6 
"y ~ f+a+k" "y ~ g+a+k" "y ~ h+a+k" "y ~ i+a+k" "y ~ j+a+k" "y ~ f+b+k" 
          7           8           9          10 
"y ~ g+b+k" "y ~ h+b+k" "y ~ i+b+k" "y ~ j+b+k"
```

It is hard to provide a more targeted help without a reproducible example.

Comment: I ended up using combn. x= names(Category[,-c(1:2)]), y = 10, combinations <- combn(x,y) and then I looped over the "combinations".